# How to handle 3D object size and its position in ARKit

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am facing difficulties with 3D object size and its x, y, z positioning. I added the 3D object to `sceneView`, but its size is too big. How do I reduce the 3D object size based on my requirement? Can anyone help me handle the 3D object's size and its x, y, z positioning?

I am using Swift to code.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you include some code? Please add specifics; we can't do all of your research for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `SCNNode` has a scale property:

> Each component of the scale vector multiplies the corresponding
>   dimension of the node’s geometry. The default scale is 1.0 in all
>   three dimensions. For example, applying a scale of (2.0, 0.5, 2.0) to
>   a node containing a cube geometry reduces its height and increases its
>   width and depth.

Which can be set as follows:

```
var scale: SCNVector3 { get set }
```

If for example your node was called `myNode`, you could thus use the following to scale it by 1/10 of it's original size:

```
myNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

Regarding positioning SCNNodes this can be achieved by setting the `position` property:

> The node’s position locates it within the coordinate system of its
>   parent, as modified by the node’s pivot property. The default position
>   is the zero vector, indicating that the node is placed at the origin
>   of the parent node’s coordinate system.

[image]

If therefore, you wanted to add your SCNNode to the center of the `worldOrigin`, and 1m away from the camera you can use the following:

```
myNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)
```

Hope it helps...